# Relationship between $A x=b$ and $A x=\lambda x$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations

Are these two things related somehow in an intuitive way?

Comment: I assume $A$ is a matrix and $x$ is a vector? And $b$ and $\lambda$ are scalars? If so, the first equation only makes sense if $x$ is an element of a one-dimensional vector space, i.e., a scalar.

Comment: @manthanomen $b$ would be a vector. $Ax = b$ is common notation for a system of equations.

Answer (score 3):

It depends; do you know $\lambda$? If so, you can reduce the second problem to a linear system by rearranging to get

$$(A-\lambda I)x = 0.$$

which is of the same form as your first problem.

If $\lambda$ is unknown and you are trying to simultaneously find $\lambda$ and $x$, then the second equation is called an *eigenvector problem* and is not equivalent to solving any single linear system.

Numerical techniques exist for finding eigenvectors, though they are both more complex and more expensive than linear solvers; some keywords to get you started include "spectral decomposition," "singular value decomposition," and "power iteration."